Declare object name in Dag to download library
I created a dag to download libraries from gcp to machine where dag would run.
Here is my dag,
gcp_file = GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator (
  taskid="my_task_id",
  object_name=str('lib1-1.0.0.jar','lib2-1.0.1.jar),
  bucket="abcd",
  dag=dag
)

but I am getting error,
TypeError:decoding str is not supported
Need to download both jar files into vm.
Also my jar files is existing under "abcd/efg/lib1-1.0.0.jar", so should i declare the full path in "bucket" param
